# Xamarin iOS application crashes on physical device but run on emulator

Tags: xamarin, ios17

I am developing an iOS application using Xamarin on Visual Studio for Windows.
My application runs perfectly on iOS device simulator but it crashes systematically after about one minute when it runs on a physical device.
The only difference I could see in the "output" window is that when it runs on the real iPhone I get a lot of "Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[68997:2083268] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly ''".
That has been happening since I updated to iOS 17.

I tried to update every single nuget package and I also tried to reacreate the references between the projects. I also updated Visual Studio and I even tried to delete all the bin and obj folders of all involved projects too but it was all unuseful.

Comment: It's probably because Apple removed `NewsstandKit` from iOS 17.0 and there is a chance that your App is referencing this Framework. You can refer to the methods in the Link([App startup crashes on iOS 17.0](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18964))

Comment: please add details about the crash to your question